# Run code when a button in a different window is pressed

Tags: c#, wpf

this is my first post.
So I've been building this WPF C# application for a couple months now and I've stumbled upon this problem.
I've created a page (the pages name is UHP) with a log-out verification feature where a Window pops up when a 'Log Out' button is clicked. The window asks whether the user would like to log out, if YES then it should navigate to the `MainWindow`, if NO then it should stay on the same page.

In code i've set the UHP page to navigate to `MainWindow` as long as the 'Log Out' button is pressed, so whether YES or NO was pressed doesn't matter. I want to detect whether the YES or NO button has been pressed in the logout verification window so that the code in UHP page only executes when YES is pressed.

**Heres the code for the Log-Out button on page (UHP):**

```
public void UserLogoutBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var lovmsgb = new Custom_MessageBoxes.LogoutVerification();
            lovmsgb.ShowDialog();

            var mainWin = new Page();
            NavigationService.Navigate(mainWin);
        }
```

**Code for Logout Verification Window:**

```
public LogoutVerification()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void YesLogoutBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void NoLogoutBtn(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
```

**MainWindow code, just in case:**

```
 private void BtnClickP1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            mainFrame.Content = new Page1();
        }

        private void MainFrame_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void AdminBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            mainFrame.Content = new Admin_Homepage();
        }
```

Comment: Please pay attention to the descriptions of tags you use. `visual-studio` is intended for questions related to the Visual Studio application, not code written within it.

Comment: Oh sorry, makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `ShowDialog()` as followed:

The *Dialog.xaml* window:

```
<Window x:Class="Dialog">
  <Grid>
    <StackPanel>
      <TextBlock Text="This is a dialog" />
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Content="Ok"
                IsDefault="True"
                Click="OkButton_OnClick"/>
        <Button Content="Cancel"
                IsCancel="True" />
      </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>

  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Because `IsCancel` is set to `True` on the cancel button, the dialog automatically returns `false` as a dialog result when the cancel button is clicked (or the dialog is closed via the close icon or Alt+F4). So there is no need for a dedicated cancel event handler. In case of the 'Ok' button the result must be explicitly set (see below).

The *Dialog.xaml.cs* code-behind 'Ok' button `Click` event handler:

```
private void OkButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  this.DialogResult = true;
}
```

The modified `UserLogoutBtn_Click` handler:

```
private void UserLogoutBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)       
{
  var dialog = new Dialog() {Owner = this};

  // Returns when the dialog window was closed
  bool? dialogResult = dialog.ShowDialog();

  if (dialogResult.Value)
  {
    // Ok was clicked
    var mainWin = new Page();
    NavigationService.Navigate(mainWin);
  }
  else
  {
    // Cancel was clicked or the window was closed
  }
}
```

Comment: in the `var dialog = new Dialog() {Owner = this};` expression, `Dialog()` gives me an error saying I should use System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleElement.Window.Dialog, when I use that it still gives me 2 errors;
Cannot create an instance of the static class "VisualStyleElement.Window.Dialog" and "VisualStyleElement.Window.Dialog" Does not contain a value for owner

Comment: It looks like you have a naming conflict. Check your using in that file. Maybe you accidently referencing the `Forms` namespace. If this is the case, remove it. If this is not the case try to fully qualify your class (`new My.Namespace.Dialog()`) or rename your class (e.g. `NavigationDialog`). But my guess is that you accidently referenced the wrong namespace.

Comment: In fact `VisualStyleElement.Window.Dialog` is a static class.The fact that th error gives yo the namespace without the `Windows.Forms` part indicates that you are already referencing `Windows.Forms`. If you need it, than fully qualify your name space or use a namespace alias.

Comment: No worries, I fixed it by changing the `Dialog()` to an instance of my LogOut Verification Window, I didnt need to use `VisualStyleElement.Window.Dialog` in the end. It works like I wanted it to, thanks

Answer (score -2):

Are you aware of MessageBox? If not - Google that. It lets you display a message and you can set the mode to show Yes/No buttons. You can write an If statement based on the button the user clicked.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of MessageBox, but the design is too plain and not customised. Since I'm using WPF, the LogOut Verification Window has a very unique custom design.